# Prepare data for Haversine distance

Tags: python, pandas, haversine

I want to calculate [haversine](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/) distance for every unique value of `id`:

```
from haversine import haversine, Unit

data = 

id latitude longitude 
a        11        22
a        33        44
b        55        66
b        77        88
c        99        11
c        12        13

start = (11,22) # (lat, lon)
end = (33,44)
haversine(start,end)*1000
```

How to create a loop for it? Because real data has 2000+ `id`s

There are good questions about Hvaersine but there is no answers concernning data preparation for that. This question is mostly about data preparation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2000 isn't that much, you can process it with a simple python loop. But if you'd prefer more pandas-native approach you can do the following:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: haversine(g.iloc[0], g.iloc[1])) * 1000
```

considering that your dataset consistently has a pair of points for each `id`.

Output:

```
id
a    3.320380e+06
b    2.601419e+06
c    9.673377e+06
```

Comment: btw, your first code is faster `haversine = data.set_index('id_easy').apply(tuple,axis=1).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: haversine(x.iat[0],x.iat[1])*1000)`