# How how to calculate haversine cross-distance between to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, haversine

Here's my dataset `B`

```
   index       lon        lat
0   0   107.071969  -6.347778
1   1   110.431361  -7.773489
2   2   111.978469  -8.065442
```

and dataset `C`

```
    index      lon        lat
5   5   112.340919  -7.520442
6   6   107.179119  -6.291131
7   7   106.807442  -6.437383
```

What I need the output is (calculation is completely ramdom)

```
           0       1        2 
  5      4.5     7.7      7.8 
  6      5.9     7.9      2.8
  7      6.7     7.7     10.2
```

What I try

```
from haversine import haversine
haversine(B,C)
```

And the outpout

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-3078154d1efc> in <module>
      1 from haversine import haversine
----> 2 haversine(B,C)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/haversine/haversine.py in haversine(point1, point2, unit)
     86 
     87     # unpack latitude/longitude
---> 88     lat1, lng1 = point1
     89     lat2, lng2 = point2
     90 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: You can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800794/prepare-data-for-haversine-distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your output distances, what units are they? I converted mine to kilometers. You can check using an online distance calculator if you wanted. Let me know

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances
pd.DataFrame(haversine_distances(np.radians(df1[['lat','lon']]),np.radians(df2[['lat','lon']]))* 6371,index=df1.index, columns=df2.index)



    5           6           7
0  596.019968   13.413123   30.882602
1  212.317223  394.942014  426.564799
2   72.573637  565.020998  598.409848
```

Comment: Work as expected